# Using Like/Regex how do I match multiple 777s variation in front of a column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a regular expression using LIKE

Goal: I want to match the first four digits to be either 7777 or 777 or 77 to be true and so that I can fetch only those values

Example Result Data

```
77777777 true 

777877777 true

773738373 true

787666871 false

777787878 true
```

How can I do something like: 
SELECT number, (REGEX('777') as col FROM table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex, this matches only if the string starts with 99, 999 or 9999: `SELECT RLIKE('9999555444', '^9{2,4}.*');`

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation 1:

You could use a regular LIKE, rather than a regular expression LIKE (RLIKE). This would simply be something like:

```
...WHERE value::varchar LIKE '99%'
```